# FTlabs/FastClick with jQm not reducing 300ms click in iOS

Tags: jquery-mobile, click, tap

I'm using the [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library to reduce the 300ms that exists after a user clicks on an anchor element in a mobile-web jqm page.

However the 300ms are still there,

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_mobile_configuration.js?body=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.mobile.js?body=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fastclick.js?body=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fastclick_config.js?body=1"></script>
```

fastclick_config.js :

```javascript
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    new FastClick(document.body);
}, false);
```

I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: What browser/device are you testing with?

Comment: Have you got a test case?  If you have, can you post an issue on https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues?state=open?

Answer (score 1):

I read elsewhere that you should use

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```